# Using screen.primaryscreen for dual display

Tags: c#, winforms, screen

I use

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
```

and

```
 Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
```

To render my window (i.e it's a percentage with all buttons etc derived from this). Will this work as expected for dual screens? Are there any situations where it won't work as expected?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height 
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
```

to avoid problems with users who have larger task bars and things.

example usage of this method can be found on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen.aspx

you may also find this of interest:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812142.aspx